# Is it possible to join the Apple Developer Program with a Visa Prepaid card?

Tags: developer-program

I have just ordered a Visa reLoad card where you simply put money on your card before you buy something. Will this work with an Apple Developers subscription?

Answer (score 3):

Visa Pre-Paid *is* a credit card. It will honored providing they can charge those $99 successfully to it. They don't really care if it's pre-paid, secured or non-secured. If they can charge it, they'll gladly accept it, like any other business would. The money is real either way.

Answer (score 2):

It's a safe bet that it ought to. I'm not sure there's any reliable way to tell what account number is a "real" credit card or debit card (i.e., linked to a checking account) vs. a prepaid debit card (like yours).

Bear in mind, though, that when it comes time to renew, the transaction will fail unless you have the funds on the card or change to a new card.